# I am getting a segmentation fault when executing my simple program written in assembly

Tags: assembly, segmentation-fault

I am learning assembly and I have just read the chapter about functions in my book. 
Here, I want to try some simple function calls based on a condition:
if val1 == val2, call func2, otherwise call func1. 
But I get a `segmentation fault` when executing the program. I cannot see where the problem is.

```
.section .data

val1: .int 25
val2: .int 50
ans1: .int 100
ans2: .int 200

.section .text

.globl _start
_start:

movl val2, %ecx     # put val2 to %ecx

cmpl val1, %ecx     # compare val1 and %ecx (val2)
je call_func2       # if val1 == val2, jump to call_func2

call_func1:         # else execute call_func1
call func1
jmp endifblock

call_func2: 
call func2          # call func2
jmp endifblock

endifblock:
nop

popl %edx           # pop result from stack into %edx

movl $1, %eax
movl %edx, %ebx     # set result (%edx) as exit code
int  $0x80

.type func1, @function     # function "func1"
func1:
pushl ans1                 # push ans1 to stack (it seems this causes the segmentation fault)
ret

.type func2, @function     # function "func2"
func2:
pushl ans2                 # push ans2 to stack (it seems this causes the segmentation fault)
ret
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies here:

```
func1:
pushl ans1
ret
```

Your "answer" from the function cannot be in the stack. If you push a value to the stack, the `ret` instruction will take that value as the address to jump to, causing the segfault.

You have to choose a register to hold the return value (usually EAX in IA32 architecture) and do something like this:

```
func1:
mov ans1, %eax
ret
```

(`func2` has of course the same problem)

Your application, after calling either `func1` or `func2`, will return the value, reading it from `EAX`, not from the stack:

```
movl %eax, %edx     # save value returned from function into EDX

movl $1, %eax
movl %edx, %ebx     # set result (%edx) as exit code
int  $0x80
```

Comment: Thanks! Actually I figured it out just after my post. So using push and pop works like this: `pushl $1` `pushl $2` and when I do `popl %eax`value 2 goes into %eax? And if I do `popl %ebx` again, then value 1 goes into %ebx? Is that correct?

Comment: Thanks! If I would like to retrieve the second most top item from the stack, how to achieve that? Is it possible? And is it possible to first store a 4 byte long in the stack and then store a 2 byte int on the stack? If the stack is containing a 4 byte long and a 2 byte int, to retrive the int, do I type `popl 2(%eax)` or simillar?

Comment: It's not a good idea to store objects of different sizes in the stack, as it could lead to misaligned memory access. On 32-bit systems, objects pushed to the stack are usually 4 bytes long, even if you want to store just a byte. If you would like to retrieve the second most top item (retrieve, but not remove), and asumming all objects are 32-bit wide, you can do like this: `mov 4(%esp),%eax`

Answer (score 1):

Segmentation fault means that one of the addresses you've tried to access, either as data or as instructions, doesn't belong to this program.

Haven't read thru this in detail, but one obvious issue: I don't see "return" at the end of your functions...

Comment: Can't I push a value in func1 or func2 and then pop it from outside the function (but AFTER the call to it)? Because it seems that it is the `pushl` instructions that causes the segmentation fault. I have also added `ret` to the functions.

Comment: You can certainly return a value on the stack...

If the push is really calling the segfault, odds are that your stack management is wrong somewhere in the program and you're running out of stack space.